# Comments in LIGO

Tags: ligo

What is the syntax for comments in LIGO?

Comment: double slash as in c++: https://ligolang.org/docs/tutorials/get-started/tezos-taco-shop-smart-contract/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PascaLIGO and CameLIGO, the block comments are anything (including UTF-8 encoded glyphs) between `(*` and `*)`. In ReasonLIGO, the delimiters are `/*` and `*/`.

In all three LIGO syntaxes, line comments are introduced by `//`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything between `//` and a new line `\n` is considered a comment by the compiler. And anything between `(*` and `*)` is also a comment.

So

```
// This is a comment

const a: nat = 4n; // and this is a comment

(* and this is also a comment *)
```

Comment: You should give people the possibility to answer your questions and not always rush to answer them yourself.

Comment: If you think there is anything to add, you are free to provide another answer. Also: I did ask this question on Slack and got an answer from the LIGO compiler developers. That's how I learned about the `(**)` notation. I am trying to provide some information here on Stack Exchange which is unfortunately lacking because the community spends too much time on Slack.

Comment: @FFF You should be telling the people hanging out on Slack that they should move their Q&As here. You are barking up the wrong tree.